# Extended Support for Windows Server 2008 on Azure

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have a SharePoint 2010 Farm on premise.
The Extended support for Windows server 2008 ends in January 2020.
The Microsoft documentation here(https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4456235/end-of-support-for-windows-server-2008-and-windows-server-2008-r2) mentions that if the Windows 2008 servers are migrated to Azure, the customers would get 3 additional years of Critical and Important security updates at no additional charge.
We would like to know if the support for SharePoint 2010 and the SQL Server 2008 R2 support would also be extended? 
What are the Microsoft guidelines for SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 can be moved to Azure to get extended support.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-new-options-for-sql-server-2008-and-windows-server-2008-end-of-support/

SharePoint 2010 extended support will end in October 2020. It looks like this is final and there won’t be any further extensions to its support.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Mainstream-support-for-SharePoint-Server-2010-ends-in-October/ba-p/272628